# What is the tmp folder in /var?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, tmp

I have a `tmp` folder in `/var` and it has the file `channel.xml` in it.

I don't know what this is and if it should be there and what permissions it should have because at the moment it is wide open.

Also what is the folder above `/var` called please?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial to get yourself familiar with Linux: http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/beginner-s-guide-to-linux-where-to-start-1066778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directory `/var/tmp` should have permissions `rwxrwxrwt`, which allow anyone to change to this directory, create and read files in this directory and write/rename/delete files they own (this last restriction is caused by the `t` in the permissions, which is the "sticky bit").

The file you see in there is a temporary file created by something on your system.  You can look at its ownership or try and see what process has it open to get a clue as to what wrote it.  The XML schema in the top of the file may also help out with that.

The folder above `/var` is `/`, also know as the `root` directory.

Comment: But when I command cd ~/ I get my root which looks nothing like when I go one up from /var with cd ..

Comment: The directory `~` is your users home directory, which is `/home/<username>` for normal users or `/root` for the superuser.

Comment: how do i access this other root, which command please? besides cd .. up from /var i mean

Comment: Use `cd /` to access the `/` directory.